# Gnuplot: calculated X tic labels for data file without X column

Tags: gnuplot

I have a binary data file that contains only one data column and no X column.
I can plot it using

```
plot 'data.bin' binary format='%double' using 0:1
```

This uses the index (column 0) for X-axis values.
Is it possible to calculate a different X value using the index? e.g. multiply the index with 5, so instead of 1,2,3,4... I would like to see 5,10,15,20,... as values on the X axis.

I found xticlabels, but I could not figure out how to use a scaled index instead of a column from my file.

Thanks,

Ginsengelf